# Word for the action of hammering when a hammer is not used?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example: While using **Mortar and Pestle**, the action is same as hammering but there is no hammer.

What is this **action** called?

Comment: I would call what I do with a pestle 'smashing', but if the action is the same as hammering, the action is called 'hammering'. You can both hammer and smash with a pestle.

Comment: @JEL So, hammering has nothing to do with a hammer in particular, you say?

Comment: I say that hammering is the action, no matter with what.

Comment: Mortar and pestle -- you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I am with @JEL.  The same is true of scoop, spoon, shovel, rake, screen, and probably more.

Comment: [Pulverizing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pulverize)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a pestle and mortar, pounding or grinding (depending on the movement). Hammering suggests a series of impacts that do not destroy (hammering on a door). Pounding suggests the possibility of wearing the hit object down (hence pounding rain - breaks up the soil). Hail 'hammers' on the roof because there is little chance it will break it (in England, anyway). 'Hitting' suggests one or a few impacts, not a series. Not hard and fast rules - "He hammered his opponent into the ground" is about violent damage to someone, but uses the image of a powerful hammer and a helpless nail to get across the inequality of the fight.

Comment: "Hammering suggests a series of impacts that do not destroy" I don't know about that. If someone described a person hammering someone else on the street, my mental picture of the scene would involve a lot of blood and crunching bones. Similarly, people intoxicated to the point of incapacitation are called "hammered" for (I believe) exactly that reason.